# In Rails, how can I selectively stop propagation when clicking icons in a clickable row?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have a table with rows like this:

```
NAME    AGE   ACTION (icons)
Alice    30   [edit] [delete]
Bob      30   [edit] [delete]
```

When I click on a row, I want to be taken to the user's show view:

```
$("tr.user_row").click ->    
    window.location = $(this).data("link")
```

Except when I click one of the icons. In that case, I want the click event to stop before it gets to the row-level link and relocates me.

Also, the delete icons have a confirm action applied to them:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("delete.png", alt: "delete", title: "delete"),
        user_path(@user), 
        remote: true, method: :delete,
        data: { confirm: sprintf("You sure you want to delete this user?") },
        class: "action-link"
%>
```

Normally I would have something like this in `users.js.coffee`:

```
$("tr.user_row a").click (e) ->
    e.stopPropagation()
```

But if I do that here, it blocks the confirm message from firing and I can't
delete users.

Is there a way to arrange this so that clicking on the row redirects except when clicking on the edit or delete icon *and* the delete icon preserves its desired behavior?

Comment: why not put the click event just on the td(s) that you want to be clickable instead of the whole tr?

Comment: @MaxWilliams That would probably be close enough for most cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I worked around this. (This was in Rails 4.0 but should work in earlier versions, too.)

First, I tagged each icon image with the class `stop-prop`:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("delete.png", alt: "delete", title: "delete",
                      class: "stop-prop"),
        user_path(@user), 
        method: :delete,
        remote: true, 
        data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this user?" },
        class: "action-link"
%>
```

Then in my `users.js.coffee` file, I replaced this:

```
$("tr.user_row").click ->    
    window.location = $(this).data("link")

$("tr.user_row a").click (e) ->
    e.stopPropagation()
```

with this:

```
# Make user row links clickable but stop propagation when icons clicked
$("tr.user_row").click (e) ->
    # Check e.target ("the DOM element that initiated the event" per jQuery
    # docs) for stop-prop class to stop event from propagating. 
    ok_to_propagate = ! $(e.target).hasClass('stop-prop');

    if ok_to_propagate
        window.location = $(this).data("link")
```

`$(e.target)` will be "the DOM element that initiated the event", i.e. when clicking on the icon, the image tag with the `stop-prop` class applied to it.